# Fitting text in UILabel - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel

I am struggling with fitting text into a UILabel. I want the width of the UILabel to be constant but I want the font size of the text to change so that all the text will be able to fit into the label. I am basically creating a menu bar with the text items: today, tomorrow, this week, next week. 
This is my label setup:

```
class MenuCell: BaseCell {

let dateLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247/255, green: 199/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    label.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
    label.numberOfLines  =   2
    label.lineBreakMode  =  NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth    =   true
    label.minimumScaleFactor           =    10/UIFont.labelFontSize
    return label
}()
```

I have specific width height size by this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
 collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width / 4, height: frame.height)

}
```

I set up these cells:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = labelnames[indexPath.item]


  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247/255, green: 199/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)

    return cell
}
```

Eventually, to add the cells to a view, I do:

```
override func setupViews(){
super.setupViews()
addSubview(dateLabel)
dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I put this whole entire view in my other view controller file right underneath the nav bar:

```
lazy var menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    mb.homeController = self
    return mb
}()
private func setupMenuBar() {
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-64-[v0(50)]", views: menuBar)    
}
```

But for some reason, the text I have does not change the font size to fit into the UIlabel cell.
Example of text trying to fit: 
`let labelnames = ["Todayyyyyyyyyy","Tomorrow", "This Week", "Next Week"]`
"Todayyyyyyyyyy" is not changing the font size to fit all the way. What other attributes show I adjust to fix my problem?

Comment: Two things, first off from a design perspective I would not recommend what you're trying to do because then "today" would look way disproportionate to the others when it would come to their font sizes. Secondly not entirely sure but I think `sizeToFit` can only shrink fonts, not enlarge them so you'd probably need to set `fontSize` to something really large like 90. Could also bruteForce by making a custom `UILabel` and then auto-adjusting it's `fontSize` on a loop using this https://medium.com/@Bitomule/getting-text-size-on-ios-bdae7521822f

Comment: I tried this: label.font = label.font.withSize(90) and it didn't work. However, with the design in perspective, I assume you're saying to make all the label texts the same size instead of customized for each different one. How would I pick a size that would fit all for keeping in mind different screen sizes? Nevermind just saw the  link

Comment: Sorry just changing the fontSize didn't work. To answer your question you shouldn't be thinking "I need to use up all the space available". What I'd do is look for a size that seems right, both visually (looking at it doesn't seem off putting) and functionally (If it's a button is it big enough for me to not have trouble tapping it) and then just stick with that. But I'm no expert, I just know that the end result of making different texts different sizes on the same screen in that situation would not be appealing. but you could check out the link I commented if you want a lead on what you want

Comment: I think the link gives a good way to get a right size for a specific string, but how would I go about auto-adjusting its fontSize on a loop

Comment: Added an answer hope it helps :) I can add the whole Playground testing code if you want to play around with it without modifying your code too much first

Comment: Are you still facing problems with this or did you work this out ? if so please select an answer or say how anything worked or not for you so we can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION #1 -- AUTO ADJUST**

Set your font size to be large and the scale it down as needed, like this:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
```

You just have to set the initial size to be gigantic.  It only scales down, not up.

The downside here is that if you do something really big, like:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 500)
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.0001
```

The height of the label will be based off the 500, by default.

**OPTION #2 -- MANUALLY ADJUST FOR TIGHTER FIT**

```
func updateLabel(_ s: String, label: UILabel) {

    var size = 222 as CGFloat
    repeat {
        let textSize = s.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:size)])
        if textSize.width <= label.frame.width {
            break
        }
        size -= 0.10

    } while (size > 4)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size)
    label.text = s
}
```

Quick sample: [video](https://youtu.be/EsjmFPfntWE) and [source code](https://bitbucket.org/drewster77/labelscaledemotest/src/master/).
The upper label uses Option #1, and the bottom label uses Option #2.

You can see that option #2 works better than the system-managed way.  It's probably more CPU intensive also, but it probably doesn't matter if you're just doing this once per label.

It could be that your label frame isn't the size you think it is, because you are only setting a **topAnchor**.  Are you also setting the others or doing a width constraint or something?

If the label is supposed to fill the cell, you could do something like this:

```
override func setupViews(){
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(dateLabel)
    dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    dateLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

The other suggestion would be to run the app in Xcode and then use the view debugger tool -- click this thing:

[image: view debugger]

This will show an exploded view of your screen in Xcode, along with the frames of all your views.  Check to see if the label is really the size you think it is.

Comment: No, this didn't change anything...the whole string is still not fitting in each uilabel

Comment: I tried my code in a test project before posting... hm.  I see you are setting it to 2 lines..  is that intended?

Comment: Take a look at the demo code and the updated answer.  My guess is you probably don't want numberOfLines=2.  But also, if this isn't working for you, then it could be the cell sizing is wrong.  Specifically, it looks like you're just setting top anchor.

Comment: Yes, my constraints were set up wrong. The size of the label was always changing to fit the text, rather than the text changing to fit the size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it (I like to use `@IBDesignable` so I can also use it freely in storyboards)

```swift
extension UIFont {
    func sizeOfString (string: String, constrainedToWidth width: Double) -> CGSize {
        return NSString(string: string).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                     options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                             attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self],
                                                             context: nil).size
    }
}

@IBDesignable public class TestLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable public var autoResize: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var resizeStep: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    func decorate() {
        // Here you can change whatever you want

        var bestFontSize: CGFloat = 1
        var testedFontSize: CGSize = self.font.withSize(bestFontSize).sizeOfString(string: self.text!, constrainedToWidth: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        while testedFontSize.width < self.frame.width && testedFontSize.height < self.frame.height {
            bestFontSize += 1
            testedFontSize = self.font.withSize(bestFontSize).sizeOfString(string: self.text!, constrainedToWidth: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        }
        self.font = self.font.withSize(bestFontSize - self.resizeStep)
    }
}
```

I just tested it out in playground so I didn't fully check it worked in the storyboard as I intended it but it should be perfectly functional although it doesn't care much for `bounds` or `contentsRect` but it's just to show how you could use it.

Still though, would not recommend doing this from a design perspective.